# Chess game in Windows Forms Part #2

Tags: c#, winforms, chess

> ***[(Part 1 here)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/128039)***
>
> *I've recently created my own 2-player chess game, no AI... at least for now. I do plan to do that in the future, so one of my concerns is if the code is flexible enough to just use the same classes in all the different modes so I can avoid rewriting the same code over and over again.*

Resuming with the other `Figure` implementations.

---

`RookPiece` Class :

```
public sealed class RookPiece : Figure
{
    public RookPiece(FigureDefinition definition) : base(definition)
    {
        Moves = RemoveFailedTurns(this, GetValidTurns());
        Moves = Moves.Distinct().ToList();
    }

    protected override List<Tuple<int, int>> GetValidTurns()
    {
        int n = 1;
        Tuple<int, int> rightMove = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1, CurrentPosition.Item2 + n);
        Tuple<int, int> topMove = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 + n, CurrentPosition.Item2);
        Tuple<int, int> leftMove = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1, CurrentPosition.Item2 - n);
        Tuple<int, int> downMove = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 - n, CurrentPosition.Item2);
        List<Tuple<int, int>> startingMoves = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
        {
            rightMove,
            topMove,
            leftMove,
            downMove
        };
        List<Tuple<int, int>> validMoves =
            startingMoves.Where(
                startingMove =>
                    !IsOutOfBounds(startingMove) && !WillCollideWithAlly(startingMove, PieceColor))
                .ToList();

        while (!IsOutOfBounds(rightMove) && !WillCollideWithAlly(rightMove, PieceColor) &&
               !WillCollideWithEnemy(rightMove, PieceColor).Item1)
        {
            validMoves.Add(rightMove);
            n++;
            rightMove = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1, CurrentPosition.Item2 + n);
            if (WillCollideWithEnemy(rightMove, PieceColor).Item1)
            {
                validMoves.Add(rightMove);
                break;
            }
        }

        n = 1;
        while (!IsOutOfBounds(topMove) && !WillCollideWithAlly(topMove, PieceColor) &&
               !WillCollideWithEnemy(topMove, PieceColor).Item1)
        {
            validMoves.Add(topMove);
            n++;
            topMove = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 + n, CurrentPosition.Item2);
            if (WillCollideWithEnemy(topMove, PieceColor).Item1)
            {
                validMoves.Add(topMove);
                break;
            }
        }

        n = 1;
        while (!IsOutOfBounds(leftMove) && !WillCollideWithAlly(leftMove, PieceColor) &&
               !WillCollideWithEnemy(leftMove, PieceColor).Item1)
        {
            validMoves.Add(leftMove);
            n++;
            leftMove = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1, CurrentPosition.Item2 - n);
            if (WillCollideWithEnemy(leftMove, PieceColor).Item1)
            {
                validMoves.Add(leftMove);
                break;
            }
        }

        n = 1;
        while (!IsOutOfBounds(downMove) && !WillCollideWithAlly(downMove, PieceColor) &&
               !WillCollideWithEnemy(downMove, PieceColor).Item1)
        {
            validMoves.Add(downMove);
            n++;
            downMove = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 - n, CurrentPosition.Item2);
            if (WillCollideWithEnemy(downMove, PieceColor).Item1)
            {
                validMoves.Add(downMove);
                break;
            }
        }
        return validMoves;
    }
}
```

`RookDefinitions` Class :

```
public class RookDefinitions
{
    private static readonly GeneratePieces generatedPieces = new GeneratePieces(Figure.FigureType.Rook, 0, 7, 7,
        ImagePaths.WhiteRookImagePath, ImagePaths.BlackRookImagePath);

    public IEnumerable<FigureDefinition> WhiteRooks = generatedPieces.GenerateWhitePieces();
    public IEnumerable<FigureDefinition> BlackRooks = generatedPieces.GenerateBlackPieces();
}
```

`QueenPiece` Class :

```
public sealed class QueenPiece : Figure
{
    public QueenPiece(FigureDefinition definition) : base(definition)
    {
        Moves = RemoveFailedTurns(this, GetValidTurns());
        Moves = Moves.Distinct().ToList();
    }

    protected override List<Tuple<int, int>> GetValidTurns()
    {
        List<Tuple<int, int>> rookMoves = GetRookMoves();
        List<Tuple<int, int>> bishopMoves = GetBishopMoves();
        List<Tuple<int, int>> validMoves = rookMoves.ToList();
        validMoves.AddRange(bishopMoves);
        return validMoves;
    }

    private List<Tuple<int, int>> GetRookMoves()
    {
        int n = 1;
        Tuple<int, int> rightMove = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1, CurrentPosition.Item2 + n);
        Tuple<int, int> topMove = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 + n, CurrentPosition.Item2);
        Tuple<int, int> leftMove = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1, CurrentPosition.Item2 - n);
        Tuple<int, int> downMove = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 - n, CurrentPosition.Item2);
        List<Tuple<int, int>> startingMoves = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
        {
            rightMove,
            topMove,
            leftMove,
            downMove
        };
        List<Tuple<int, int>> validMoves =
            startingMoves.Where(
                startingMove =>
                    !IsOutOfBounds(startingMove) && !WillCollideWithAlly(startingMove, PieceColor))
                .ToList();

        while (!IsOutOfBounds(rightMove) && !WillCollideWithAlly(rightMove, PieceColor) &&
               !WillCollideWithEnemy(rightMove, PieceColor).Item1)
        {
            validMoves.Add(rightMove);
            n++;
            rightMove = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1, CurrentPosition.Item2 + n);
            if (WillCollideWithEnemy(rightMove, PieceColor).Item1)
            {
                validMoves.Add(rightMove);
                break;
            }
        }

        n = 1;
        while (!IsOutOfBounds(topMove) && !WillCollideWithAlly(topMove, PieceColor) &&
               !WillCollideWithEnemy(topMove, PieceColor).Item1)
        {
            validMoves.Add(topMove);
            n++;
            topMove = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 + n, CurrentPosition.Item2);
            if (WillCollideWithEnemy(topMove, PieceColor).Item1)
            {
                validMoves.Add(topMove);
                break;
            }
        }

        n = 1;
        while (!IsOutOfBounds(leftMove) && !WillCollideWithAlly(leftMove, PieceColor) &&
               !WillCollideWithEnemy(leftMove, PieceColor).Item1)
        {
            validMoves.Add(leftMove);
            n++;
            leftMove = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1, CurrentPosition.Item2 - n);
            if (WillCollideWithEnemy(leftMove, PieceColor).Item1)
            {
                validMoves.Add(leftMove);
                break;
            }
        }

        n = 1;
        while (!IsOutOfBounds(downMove) && !WillCollideWithAlly(downMove, PieceColor) &&
               !WillCollideWithEnemy(downMove, PieceColor).Item1)
        {
            validMoves.Add(downMove);
            n++;
            downMove = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 - n, CurrentPosition.Item2);
            if (WillCollideWithEnemy(downMove, PieceColor).Item1)
            {
                validMoves.Add(downMove);
                break;
            }
        }
        return validMoves;
    }

    private List<Tuple<int, int>> GetBishopMoves()
    {
        int n = 1;
        Tuple<int, int> rightUpDiagonal = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 + n, CurrentPosition.Item2 + n);
        Tuple<int, int> leftUpDiagonal = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 + n, CurrentPosition.Item2 - n);
        Tuple<int, int> rightDownDiagonal = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 - n, CurrentPosition.Item2 + n);
        Tuple<int, int> leftDownDiagonal = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 - n, CurrentPosition.Item2 - n);
        List<Tuple<int, int>> startingMoves = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
        {
            rightUpDiagonal,
            leftUpDiagonal,
            rightDownDiagonal,
            leftDownDiagonal
        };
        List<Tuple<int, int>> validMoves =
            startingMoves.Where(
                startingMove =>
                    !IsOutOfBounds(startingMove) && !WillCollideWithAlly(startingMove, PieceColor))
                .ToList();

        while (!IsOutOfBounds(rightUpDiagonal) && !WillCollideWithAlly(rightUpDiagonal, PieceColor) &&
               !WillCollideWithEnemy(rightUpDiagonal, PieceColor).Item1)
        {
            validMoves.Add(rightUpDiagonal);
            n++;
            rightUpDiagonal = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 + n, CurrentPosition.Item2 + n);
            if (WillCollideWithEnemy(rightUpDiagonal, PieceColor).Item1)
            {
                validMoves.Add(rightUpDiagonal);
                break;
            }
        }

        n = 1;
        while (!IsOutOfBounds(leftUpDiagonal) && !WillCollideWithAlly(leftUpDiagonal, PieceColor) &&
               !WillCollideWithEnemy(leftUpDiagonal, PieceColor).Item1)
        {
            validMoves.Add(leftUpDiagonal);
            n++;
            leftUpDiagonal = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 + n, CurrentPosition.Item2 - n);
            if (WillCollideWithEnemy(leftUpDiagonal, PieceColor).Item1)
            {
                validMoves.Add(leftUpDiagonal);
                break;
            }
        }

        n = 1;
        while (!IsOutOfBounds(rightDownDiagonal) && !WillCollideWithAlly(rightDownDiagonal, PieceColor) &&
               !WillCollideWithEnemy(rightDownDiagonal, PieceColor).Item1)
        {
            validMoves.Add(rightDownDiagonal);
            n++;
            rightDownDiagonal = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 - n, CurrentPosition.Item2 + n);
            if (WillCollideWithEnemy(rightDownDiagonal, PieceColor).Item1)
            {
                validMoves.Add(rightDownDiagonal);
                break;
            }
        }

        n = 1;
        while (!IsOutOfBounds(leftDownDiagonal) && !WillCollideWithAlly(leftDownDiagonal, PieceColor) &&
               !WillCollideWithEnemy(leftDownDiagonal, PieceColor).Item1)
        {
            validMoves.Add(leftDownDiagonal);
            n++;
            leftDownDiagonal = new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 - n, CurrentPosition.Item2 - n);
            if (WillCollideWithEnemy(leftDownDiagonal, PieceColor).Item1)
            {
                validMoves.Add(leftDownDiagonal);
                break;
            }
        }
        return validMoves;
    }
}
```

`QueenDefinitions` Class :

```
public class QueenDefinitions
{
    private static readonly GeneratePieces generatedPices = new GeneratePieces(Figure.FigureType.Queen, 3, 3, 1,
        ImagePaths.WhiteQueenImagePath, ImagePaths.BlackQueenImagePath);

    public IEnumerable<FigureDefinition> WhiteQueens = generatedPices.GenerateWhitePieces();
    public IEnumerable<FigureDefinition> BlackQueens = generatedPices.GenerateBlackPieces();
}
```

`KingPiece` Class :

```
public sealed class KingPiece : Figure
{
    public KingPiece(FigureDefinition definition) : base(definition)
    {
        Moves = RemoveFailedTurns(this, GetValidTurns());
        Moves = Moves.Distinct().ToList();
    }

    protected override List<Tuple<int, int>> GetValidTurns()
    {
        List<Tuple<int, int>> tempMoves = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
        {
            new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 + 1, CurrentPosition.Item2),
            new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1, CurrentPosition.Item2 + 1),
            new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 - 1, CurrentPosition.Item2),
            new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1, CurrentPosition.Item2 - 1),
            new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 + 1, CurrentPosition.Item2 + 1),
            new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 + 1, CurrentPosition.Item2 - 1),
            new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 - 1, CurrentPosition.Item2 + 1),
            new Tuple<int, int>(CurrentPosition.Item1 - 1, CurrentPosition.Item2 - 1)
        };
        List<Tuple<int, int>> validMoves =
            tempMoves.Where(
                tempMove =>
                    !IsOutOfBounds(tempMove) && !WillCollideWithAlly(tempMove, PieceColor))
                .ToList();
        return validMoves;
    }
}
```

`KingDefinitions` Class :

```
public class KingDefinitions
{
    private static readonly GeneratePieces generatedPieces = new GeneratePieces(Figure.FigureType.King, 4, 4, 1,
        ImagePaths.WhiteKingImagePath, ImagePaths.BlackKingImagePath);

    public IEnumerable<FigureDefinition> BlackKings = generatedPieces.GenerateBlackPieces();
    public IEnumerable<FigureDefinition> WhiteKings = generatedPieces.GenerateWhitePieces();
}
```

---

Every `FigureDefinition` class uses a class called `GeneratePieces`. So here it is it basically shortens more repetitive code. It uses the `FigureDefinition` class which you can see in [part 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/128039):

```
public class GeneratePieces
{
    private readonly FigureType pieceType;
    private readonly int startingRowWhite = 0;
    private readonly int startingRowBlack = 7;
    private readonly int startingColumn;
    private readonly int endingColumn;
    private readonly int increase;
    private readonly string whitePieceImagePath;
    private readonly string blackPieceImagePath;

    public GeneratePieces(FigureType pieceType,int startingColumn,int endingColumn,int increase, string whitePieceImagePath, string blackPieceImagePath)
    {
        this.pieceType = pieceType;
        this.startingColumn = startingColumn;
        this.endingColumn = endingColumn;
        this.increase = increase;
        this.whitePieceImagePath = whitePieceImagePath;
        this.blackPieceImagePath = blackPieceImagePath;
        if (pieceType == FigureType.Pawn)
        {
            startingRowWhite = 1;
            startingRowBlack = 6;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<FigureDefinition> GenerateBlackPieces()
    {
        List<FigureDefinition> pieces = new List<FigureDefinition>();

        for (int i = startingColumn; i <= endingColumn; i += increase)
        {
            CooperativeForm.Board[startingRowBlack][i] = true;
            FigureDefinition piece = new FigureDefinition
            {
                PieceColor = FigureColor.Black,
                PieceType = pieceType,
                PieceImage = Image.FromFile(blackPieceImagePath),
                StartingPosition = new Tuple<int, int>(startingRowBlack, i),
                CurrentPosition = new Tuple<int, int>(startingRowBlack, i),
                WasMoved = false
            };
            pieces.Add(piece);

        }
        return pieces;
    }

    public IEnumerable<FigureDefinition> GenerateWhitePieces()
    {
        List<FigureDefinition> pieces = new List<FigureDefinition>();

        for (int i = startingColumn; i <= endingColumn; i += increase)
        {
            CooperativeForm.Board[startingRowWhite][i] = true;
            FigureDefinition piece = new FigureDefinition
            {
                PieceColor = FigureColor.White,
                PieceType = pieceType,
                PieceImage = Image.FromFile(whitePieceImagePath),
                StartingPosition = new Tuple<int, int>(startingRowWhite, i),
                CurrentPosition = new Tuple<int, int>(startingRowWhite, i),
            };
            pieces.Add(piece);
        }

        return pieces;
    }
}
```

We also have the `public static` Class `ImagePaths` which basically holds some locations of the figure's images :

```
public static class ImagePaths
{
    private const string assetsPath = @"Assets\Figures\";

    public static string BlackPawnImagePath { get; } = assetsPath + @"Black\b-peshka.png";
    public static string WhitePawnImagePath { get; } = assetsPath + @"White\w-peshka.png";

    public static string BlackKnightImagePath { get; } = assetsPath + @"Black\b-kon.png";
    public static string WhiteKnightImagePath { get; } = assetsPath + @"White\w-kon.png";

    public static string BlackBishopImagePath { get; } = assetsPath + @"Black\b-oficer.png";
    public static string WhiteBishopImagePath { get; } = assetsPath + @"White\w-oficer.png";

    public static string BlackRookImagePath { get; } = assetsPath + @"Black\b-top.png";
    public static string WhiteRookImagePath { get; } = assetsPath + @"White\w-top.png";

    public static string BlackQueenImagePath { get; } = assetsPath + @"Black\b-kralica.png";
    public static string WhiteQueenImagePath { get; } = assetsPath + @"White\w-kralica.png";

    public static string BlackKingImagePath { get; } = assetsPath + @"Black\b-kral.png";
    public static string WhiteKingImagePath { get; } = assetsPath + @"White\w-kral.png";
}
```

The `CooperativeModeForm` also use's the `Rochade` Class which is implemented like this :

```
using static GLS_Chess.Figures.Figure;
public class Rochade
{
    private enum RochadesByColor
    {
        White,
        Black
    }
    public Figure RochadeRook { get; private set; } = null;
    public Figure RochadeKing { get; private set; } = null;
    private static readonly List<Tuple<int, int>[]> longRochadeMoves = new List<Tuple<int, int>[]>
    {
        new[] {new Tuple<int, int>(0, 2), new Tuple<int, int>(0, 3)},
        new[] {new Tuple<int, int>(7, 2), new Tuple<int, int>(7, 3)},
    };

    private static readonly List<Tuple<int, int>[]> shortRochadeMoves = new List<Tuple<int, int>[]>
    {
        new[] {new Tuple<int, int>(0, 6), new Tuple<int, int>(0, 5)},
        new[] {new Tuple<int, int>(7, 6), new Tuple<int, int>(7, 5)},
    };

    public static Tuple<int, int> newKingMove { get; set; }

    public void DoRochade(Figure kingToBeMoved)
    {
        if (kingToBeMoved.PieceType != FigureType.King ||
            !Equals(kingToBeMoved.CurrentPosition, kingToBeMoved.StartingPosition) || kingToBeMoved.WasMoved ||
            kingToBeMoved.WillCollideWithEnemy(newKingMove, kingToBeMoved.PieceColor).Item1 ||
            kingToBeMoved.WillCollideWithAlly(newKingMove, kingToBeMoved.PieceColor))
        {
            return;
        }
        List<Figure> currentTeamFigures = kingToBeMoved.PieceColor == FigureColor.Black
            ? CooperativeForm.BlackFigures
            : CooperativeForm.WhiteFigures;
        List<Figure> enemyTeamFigures = kingToBeMoved.PieceColor == FigureColor.Black
            ? CooperativeForm.WhiteFigures
            : CooperativeForm.BlackFigures;
        if (enemyTeamFigures.Any(enemyTeamFigure => enemyTeamFigure.Moves.Contains(kingToBeMoved.CurrentPosition)))
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (var currentAllyFigure in currentTeamFigures.Where(figure => figure.PieceType == FigureType.Rook))
        {
            if (!IsLongRochade(kingToBeMoved, currentAllyFigure) &&
                !IsShortRochade(kingToBeMoved, currentAllyFigure))
            {
                continue;
            }
            List<Tuple<int, int>[]> rochadeMoves = IsLongRochade(kingToBeMoved, currentAllyFigure)
                ? longRochadeMoves
                : shortRochadeMoves;

            int rochadeArrayIndex = currentAllyFigure.PieceColor == FigureColor.Black
                ? (int) RochadesByColor.Black
                : (int) RochadesByColor.White;

            RochadeRook = new RookPiece(new FigureDefinition
            {
                StartingPosition = currentAllyFigure.StartingPosition,
                CurrentPosition = rochadeMoves[rochadeArrayIndex][1],
                PieceColor = currentAllyFigure.PieceColor,
                PieceType = FigureType.Rook,
                PieceImage = currentAllyFigure.PieceImage,
                WasMoved = true
            });
            RochadeKing = new KingPiece(new FigureDefinition
            {
                StartingPosition = currentAllyFigure.StartingPosition,
                CurrentPosition = rochadeMoves[rochadeArrayIndex][0],
                PieceColor = currentAllyFigure.PieceColor,
                PieceType = FigureType.King,
                PieceImage = kingToBeMoved.PieceImage,
                WasMoved = true
            });
            break;
        }
    }
    private static bool IsLongRochade(Figure king, Figure rook)
    {
        bool found = longRochadeMoves.Any(t => Equals(t[0], newKingMove));
        if (!found)
        {
            return false;
        }
        int arrayIndex = king.PieceColor == FigureColor.White ? 0 : 1;
        if (Equals(rook.CurrentPosition, rook.StartingPosition))
        {
            return longRochadeMoves.Where((t, i) => rook.Moves.Contains(longRochadeMoves[arrayIndex][i])).Any();
        }
        return false;
    }
    private static bool IsShortRochade(Figure king, Figure rook)
    {
        bool found = shortRochadeMoves.Any(t => Equals(t[0], newKingMove));
        if (!found)
        {
            return false;
        }
        int arrayIndex = king.PieceColor == FigureColor.White ? 0 : 1;
        if (Equals(rook.CurrentPosition, rook.StartingPosition))
        {
            return shortRochadeMoves.Where((t, i) => rook.Moves.Contains(shortRochadeMoves[arrayIndex][i])).Any();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And we also have the `PassedTurn` Class which makes the *Turn Tracking* feature possible :

```
public class PassedTurns
{
    public enum ListsOrder
    {
        WhitePlayer,
        BlackPlayer,
        PieceType,
        Action
    }

    public enum ItemsOrder
    {
        Position,
        PieceType,
        Action
    }
    private object Actions = new object();
    private object Positions = new object();
    private object PieceTypes = new object();

    public void AddNewMove(Tuple<int, int> newTurnPosition, FigureType newTurnPieceType, string newTurnAction)
    {
        Actions = newTurnAction;
        Positions = newTurnPosition;
        PieceTypes = newTurnPieceType;
    }

    public List<object> GetPassedTurns()
    {
        return new List<object>
        {
            Positions,
            PieceTypes,
            Actions,
        };
    }
}
```

---

### Reaching the end of the <s>post</s> board

Lastly (phew!), the `ReplacePawnForm` is invoked whenever a pawn reaches the end of the board and must be replaced with a figure chosen by the user:

[image: ReplacePawn form]

```
public partial class ReplacePawnForm : Form
{
    private enum ImageIndexes
    {
        Queen,
        Rook,
        Bishop,
        Knight
    }
    public Figure ReplacedFigure { get; private set; }

    private FigureType replacedFigureType;
    private string[] imagePaths;
    private readonly PictureBox[] piecesPictureBoxs = new PictureBox[4];
    private readonly Panel[] piecesPanels = new Panel[4];
    private bool pressedPictureBox = false;
    private readonly Tuple<int, int> pawnCurrentPosition;
    private readonly FigureColor pieceColor;

    private readonly FigureType[] pieceTypes =
    {
        FigureType.Queen, FigureType.Rook,
        FigureType.Bishop, FigureType.Knight,
    };

    public ReplacePawnForm(FigureColor pieceColor,Tuple<int,int> pawnCurrentPosition)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetImagePaths(pieceColor);
        SetPanels();
        SetPictureBoxs();
        CreateLabels();
        this.pieceColor = pieceColor;
        this.pawnCurrentPosition = pawnCurrentPosition;
    }

    private void bDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pressedPictureBox)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"You haven't picked a figure yet !");
        }
        else
        {
            SetReplacedFigure();
            Close();
        }
    }

    private void SetImagePaths(FigureColor inputPieceColor)
    {
        if (inputPieceColor == FigureColor.Black)
        {
            imagePaths = new[]
            {
                ImagePaths.BlackQueenImagePath, ImagePaths.BlackRookImagePath, ImagePaths.BlackBishopImagePath,
                ImagePaths.BlackKnightImagePath
            };
        }
        else
        {
            imagePaths = new[]
            {
                ImagePaths.WhiteQueenImagePath, ImagePaths.WhiteRookImagePath, ImagePaths.WhiteBishopImagePath,
                ImagePaths.WhiteKnightImagePath
            };
        }
    }

    private void SetPanels()
    {
        int horizontal = 20;
        const int vertical = 55;
        for (int i = 0; i < piecesPanels.Length; i++)
        {
            piecesPanels[i] = new Panel
            {
                Location = new Point(horizontal,vertical),
                Size = new Size(105,95)
            };
            Controls.Add(piecesPanels[i]);
            horizontal += 125;
        }
    }
    private void SetPictureBoxs()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < piecesPictureBoxs.Length; i++)
        {
            piecesPictureBoxs[i] = new PictureBox
            {
                BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(imagePaths[i]),
                BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
                Size = new Size(100,90),
                Name = i.ToString()
            };
            piecesPictureBoxs[i].Click += PictureBox_Click;
            Controls.Add(piecesPictureBoxs[i]);
            piecesPanels[i].Controls.Add(piecesPictureBoxs[i]);
        }
    }
    private void PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RemoveBackgroundColor();
        pressedPictureBox = true;
        PictureBox currentPb = (PictureBox) sender;
        GetContainerPanel(currentPb).BackColor = Color.DarkCyan;
        replacedFigureType = GetFigureType(currentPb);
    }

    private FigureType GetFigureType(Control currentPb)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < imagePaths.Length; i++)
        {
            if (currentPb.Name == i.ToString())
            {
                return pieceTypes[i];
            }
        }
        return FigureType.Queen;
    }
    private Panel GetContainerPanel(Control currentPb)
    {
        return piecesPanels.FirstOrDefault(piecesPanel => piecesPanel.Controls.Contains(currentPb));
    }

    private void RemoveBackgroundColor()
    {
        foreach (var piecesPanel in piecesPanels)
        {
            piecesPanel.BackColor = DefaultBackColor;
        }
    }

    private void CreateLabels()
    {
        Label[] labels = new Label[piecesPictureBoxs.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < labels.Length; i++)
        {
            labels[i] = new Label
            {
                Location =
                    new Point(piecesPanels[i].Location.X + piecesPanels[i].Width/4,
                        piecesPanels[i].Location.Y + piecesPanels[i].Height),
                Text = pieceTypes[i].ToString(),
                Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
            };
            Controls.Add(labels[i]);
        }
    }

    private void SetReplacedFigure()
    {
        switch (replacedFigureType)
        {
            case FigureType.Bishop:
                ReplacedFigure = new BishopPiece(new FigureDefinition
                {
                    PieceType = FigureType.Bishop,
                    PieceImage = Image.FromFile(imagePaths[(int) ImageIndexes.Bishop]),
                    CurrentPosition = pawnCurrentPosition,
                    StartingPosition = pawnCurrentPosition,
                    PieceColor = pieceColor,
                    WasMoved = true
                });
                break;
            case FigureType.Knight:
                ReplacedFigure = new KnightPiece(new FigureDefinition
                {
                    PieceType = FigureType.Knight,
                    PieceImage = Image.FromFile(imagePaths[(int) ImageIndexes.Knight]),
                    CurrentPosition = pawnCurrentPosition,
                    StartingPosition = pawnCurrentPosition,
                    PieceColor = pieceColor,
                    WasMoved = true
                });
                break;
            case FigureType.Rook:
                ReplacedFigure = new RookPiece(new FigureDefinition
                {
                    PieceType = FigureType.Rook,
                    PieceImage = Image.FromFile(imagePaths[(int) ImageIndexes.Rook]),
                    CurrentPosition = pawnCurrentPosition,
                    StartingPosition = pawnCurrentPosition,
                    PieceColor = pieceColor,
                    WasMoved = true
                });
                break;
            case FigureType.Queen:
                ReplacedFigure = new QueenPiece(new FigureDefinition
                {
                    PieceType = FigureType.Queen,
                    PieceImage = Image.FromFile(imagePaths[(int) ImageIndexes.Queen]),
                    CurrentPosition = pawnCurrentPosition,
                    StartingPosition = pawnCurrentPosition,
                    PieceColor = pieceColor,
                    WasMoved = true
                });
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a number of different points to make in each post, but also a number of points that apply to both. I don't think you *had* to list *all* implementations  of `Figure`;  one interesting piece and then apply what you learn to the rest of 'em, and then follow-up with another post that shows improvements from the previous reviews, perhaps applied to another interesting piece. That way you post more digestible code that earns you more in-depth reviews. [Please take a minute to read this meta post](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6736/23788).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Some of the terminology you're using is unusual. I would say `Piece` or `Man` instead of `Figure`, and "castling" instead of "Rochade". `GetValidTurns` should probably be called `GetValidMoves`.
- As Eric Lippert suggests on [your other question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128039/chess-game-in-windows-forms-part-1), you should probably create a struct called `BoardPosition` which contains a row and a column as `int`s.

  - The code for `BoardPosition` should contain comments indicating how the ranks and files are numbered. Maybe the constructor should check that the given numbers are in range.
  - It would be useful for `BoardPosition` to have a method `public BoardPosition Move(int right, int up)` which returns a new `BoardPosition` with the coordinates altered appropriately.
- If you wanted, you could make `GetValidTurns` on `QueenPiece` just a single line: `return GetRookMoves().Concat(GetBishopMoves()).ToList();`
- The methods `GetValidTurns` on `RookPiece` and `GetRookMoves` on `QueenPiece` are very similar. Consider replacing these two methods with a single `GetRookMoves` method. You might have this method as a protected method in the `Figure` class, or perhaps as a static method in a new static class, called something like `ChessMoves` or (Eric's suggestion) `Rulebook`.
- In `GetRookMoves`, the while-loops for `rightMove`, `topMove`, `leftMove`, and `downMove` are all very similar. See if you can combine these four pieces of code into one.
- I find the method call `WillCollideWithEnemy(rightMove, PieceColor).Item1` to be confusing. Given the name `WillCollideWithEnemy`, I would expect that method to return a `bool`, but a `bool` doesn't have an `Item1`. Consider doing the following instead:

  - Create a method `public Figure GetEnemyAt(boardPosition, pieceColor)`, which returns `null` if the square at `boardPosition` is empty or contains an allied piece.
  - Create a separate method `public bool ContainsEnemy(boardPosition, pieceColor)`, which merely checks if the square contains an enemy or not and returns `true` or `false`. (This method could be implemented as a one-liner: `return (GetEnemyAt(boardPosition, pieceColor) != null);`.)
- For the while-loops in `GetRookMoves`, the logic seems a little more complicated than necessary.

  - The `startingMoves` variable isn't necessary. Remove it, and initialize `validMoves` as the empty list.
  - The implementation of the while-loops could be something like the following:

—

```
BoardPosition destination = CurrentPosition;
while(true)
{
    destination = destination.Move(right: 1, up: 0);
    if (IsOutOfBounds(destination) || WillCollideWithAlly(destination, PieceColor))
    {
        break;
    }
    validMoves.Add(destination);
    if (ContainsEnemy(destination, PieceColor))
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

- Consider making all of the members of `ImagePaths` `const` instead of `static`. You should be able to use definitions such as `public const string BlackPawnImagePath = assetsPath + @"Black\b-peshka.png";`. (Making `ImagePaths` a static class was a good idea.)
- Consider making `Rochade` a static class and turning all of its non-constant properties (including `newKingMove`) into parameters and/or local variables of the methods.
- In the `PassedTurns` class, shouldn't `Actions`, `Positions`, and `PieceTypes` all be lists?

Comment: "It would be useful for BoardPosition to have a method public BoardPosition Move(int right, int up) which returns a new BoardPosition with the coordinates altered appropriately." - Good idea. I might use this idea in my own chess program.